# Does Geocoder work outside the United States?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

Can the Geocoder class provide reverse lookups outside of the United States? I basically want to know what country my user is in (for law stuff).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

If it can't, is there another way of determining this?

Thanks

Comment: Huh. Weird. I just wrote a quick app to test it (i'm in Estonia) and wasn't able to geocode my location on my HTC Desire, the `Geocoder` just returned an empty list. I would have expected it to work.

Comment: Oh bother.. it sometimes doesn't work in the US - did you try it a few times?

Comment: A few months ago it worked for sure in Austria for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested Geocoding before in Poland, so I would say it should work outside the USA. I think it will work everywhere where Google Maps API geocoding works. Here is a [list](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) of locations where it works, however I don't know if it is outdated. You could also get the user's country by using his/her IP address, but probably this will require more work.